# Does the wheel needs to be replaced

Tags: tires, wheels

I recently hit a curb while turning left around 20mph. THe tire rim has been scuffed a lot at the edge and it poked a hole on the tire sidewall that caused the tire to be punctured. I am going to replace the tire. Do I need to replace the wheel or can I sand it off and have it reused? Please advice. If it doesn't need to be replaced please advice on how it could be fixed?

[image: Wheel front closeup]
[image: Wheel front]
[image: Wheel view side right]
[image: Wheel view side left]

Thanks

Comment: Wheel and tire health questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @jwh20 - Well, technically, only tire health questions are off topic. I believe this question can be quantitatively answered.

Comment: You need to get it checked by someone who knows what they are looking at.  There could be a crack somewhere else on the wheel that we can’t see.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. Other than the dent , the wheel may be deformed. I dented a wheel that did not look as bad as the picture. I ground and sanded the area so it was not noticeable and got a new tire. The new tire could not be balanced because the wheel had been distorted. The distortion could not be seen by eye and required measurements to find. It could not be reasonably be fixed. I think your best option is a replacement wheel.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: maybe.**

This is one of those tricky situations that may not mesh with your reckon of how things should go. Here are some of the wheel failure modes that I can think of quickly that won't be obvious to the casual viewer but will be something that a professional technician in this area will be able to investigate:

1. The wheel could be cracked and might fail disastrously. To be honest, I think this is unlikely with what looks like a nasty case of curb rash.
2. The wheel could be bent out of its necessary circular shape. Again, it doesn't look like this is what happened when it got curbed but it's not impossible.
3. The wheel could be bent locally and the tire bead won't seat. This will be immediately obvious to the tire technician since a wheel like this wouldn't hold pressure.
4. The wheel could just be scuffed and is otherwise fine. I have wheels that have similar scuffs to this in my family's little fleet and I tend to keep them that way as badges of shame. Be more careful of the nice wheels unless you want them to look like... *this!* **Cue dramatic music**

In short, this isn't something that a bunch of (admittedly helpful) people on the internet can solve for you. I'd strongly recommend that you have a conversation with a tire tech that you feel that you can trust.